# Not able click on a link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code is this:

```
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.truereligion.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Header1_wcLocalization_imgShippingCountryFlag")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame("__cvo_iframe");
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/input")));
    element.click();
    driver.close();
```

Getting **Exception**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException:
    Unable to locate element :
                             { "method":   "xpath",
                               "selector": "html/body/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/input"
                             }"
```

**How can this issue get solved?**

Comment: right number of divs?

Comment: please give html code of the element u r tryin to click on

Comment: Please open "http://www.truereligion.com/" site.. i am clicking on India & later want select "Proceed as US customer" link

Comment: "Proceed as US customer" link contains very good id. Why you use xPath?? driver.findElement(By.Css("#ProceedAsUSuser"));. P.S. For future forget about xpaths, it's very very bad solution for searching elements on the page.

Comment: Agree. I tried all locators. But i was not able to locate element. by css also i am not able to select

Comment: @CSwami The frame you're trying to switch is wrong. I have posted my answer, which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code:

- The frame id your trying to switch to(its class name  `iframeIntPop`) is different to the one you have written(`__cvo_iframe`) in your code.
- The XPath for `Proceed as US user` is also wrong

This below code works,

```
            driver.get("http://www.truereligion.com/");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" #header-secondary > div > ul")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Header1_wcLocalization_imgShippingCountryFlag")).click();

           WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='_CHtmlForm1']/div[5]/iframe")));
           WebElement frameID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='_CHtmlForm1']/div[5]/iframe"));
           driver.switchTo().frame(frameID);
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ProceedAsUSuser']")));
           WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ProceedAsUSuser']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to click like this:

```
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ProceedAsUSuser")));
element.click();
```

Comment: try to access it via parent form: `By.Xpath("//form[@id='Form1']//input[@id='ProceedAsUSuser']")` or `By.Css("form[id='Form1'] input[id='ProceedAsUSuser']")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "__cvo_iframe" wrong locator i think for frame which will appear after clicking on 'India & later" link (but not sure). Anyway, below working C# code which will click on link, switch to frame and click on "ProceedAsUser" link. Add waiting time if needed between actions:

```
            //Creates ChromeDriver
            var driver = CreateBrowser("http://www.truereligion.com/");
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#Header1_wcLocalization_lnkInternationalWebsite")).Click();
            var frame = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".iframeIntPop"));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#ProceedAsUSuser")).Click();
```

P.S. FYI, This site doesn't work in FF (25 ver). Site shown as I logged to it from mobile device "http://m.truereligion.com/?l=US&c=USD"